# Where to create .env file in a vue3 cli project?

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, vuejs3, development-environment, production-environment

I have built a project with Vue3-CLI.

I'm going to use `.env` and `.env.development` files in my project.

I created these files but `process.env` does not contain my variables such as `SERVER_ROOT`.

I have created these files in Vue-root (called @/ in Vue projects). Isn't it correct? If not, where to create `.env` files correctly?

**NOTE**: I tested `console.dir(process.env)` and this is the result in the console:

```
BASE_URL: "/"
NODE_ENV: "development"
```

Comment: You're probably using Vite and not Webpack, hence this is relevant: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files

Comment: Im not using vite friend.

Comment: Please define `vue3-cli` then. This? https://cli.vuejs.org/ You should be using this nowadays: https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#creating-a-vue-application

Comment: how this starting guide will guide me to start using .env files guy?

Comment: We need to be sure of the bundler you're using. That will avoid a lot of pain and time consumption (on both sides). Or you can also provide a [repro], even better.

Comment: I started my project by cloning the official Vue-CLI using `yarn global add @vue/cli` and `vue create someproject`, I think Im using webpack as bundler. I added `PWA`, `Router` and `CSS pre-processor (LESS)` as plugins, not `Vuex` nor `Typescript`.

Comment: So yeah, the first CLI that I linked aka: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html Do not use that one, it's not the recommended way nowadays. It is also from what I'm seeing, using Vite (if talking about Vue3 of course).

Answer (score 1):

I understood why I wasn't able to use my environment variable (`SERVER_ROOT`)

It was only because every environment variable in Vue3-CLI should start with **`VUE_APP_`** and I was trying to make an env variable called `SERVER_ROOT` instead of ***`VUE_APP_SERVER_ROOT`***.

Comment: For webpack yes: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables I still recommend not using that one. Vue2 is End of Life by the end of the year and you probably want to use the latest stable Vue3 and Vite as a whole.

Comment: friend I use Vue3 but I don't use Vite plugin. Vue3 does not equal to Vite...